# Golang Json Marshall encoding synthax

Tags: json, encoding, go

i would know if json.Marshal Put Uppercase a the first letter  of each name fields ? I need to encode some data with just a lowercase at each field name first letter.

just:

```
{
  "name":"thomas"
}
```

instead of:

```
{
  "Name":"thomas"
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add an annotation to the `Name` field.

Supposing your struct is:

```
type User struct {
    Name string
 }
```

You have to change it to:

```
type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
 }
```

The json marshaller will replace `Name` with `name`